# android API28: can not write into file that was created before

Tags: java, android

I have the problem, that i can not write into existing file with my android app. Pressing the button once, creates the file and writes the line into it. But pressing the button after that does nothing. I really cant find the mistake.

```
String filePath = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + "test.txt";
```

On create i ask for permissions, which are also set in the manifest.xml

```
        String[] permissions = {Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};
    requestPermissions(permissions,1);
```

My function on clicking:

```
    View.OnClickListener myhandler2 = new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        try {
            final Path path = Paths.get(filePath);
            Files.write(path, Arrays.asList("line"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8,
                    Files.exists(path) ? StandardOpenOption.APPEND : StandardOpenOption.CREATE);
        } catch (final IOException e) {
        }
```

After clicking the button several times and opening the file in a seperate editor show only the first line. But Files.readAllLines(path).toString() shows every thing.

**EDIT:**OK, code works like a charm. I had the phone pluged into my computer and refreshing the directory under windows showed only if a new file was created. Changes in files were only visible after unplugging and reconnecting the phone. Does someone has an explanation for that behavior?
**EDIT2:**I used Windows explorer to navigate to the file and opened it with a texteditor. Changes were not visible. However using the build in android studio device file explorer (View > Tool Windows > Device File Explorer) and open the file in android studio showed every change.

Answer (score 0):

Your code swallows possible exceptions that may contain the reason what went wrong:

Add this to your app and see what the error message is:

```
    } catch (final Exception e) {
         // could be SecurityException some permission issu, IOException i.e file locked, invalid filePath
         Log.e("MyApName", "cannot append to '" + filePath+
                            "'", e);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I removed the exception handling in the code snippet above for readability. No exception is thrown...

Comment: your code catches IOException mine catches Exception. no generic Exception caught?

Comment: No Exception or IOException. Have you read my edits in the question from yesterday?